# Django Environment Variables coming from docker-compose.yml but don't effect the project

Tags: django, docker-compose

I have been working on this all day and I am completely confused.

I have create a Django project and using docker and a docker-compose.yml to hold my environment variables. I was struggling to get the DEBUG variable to be False. But I have since found out that my SECRET_KEY isn't working either.

I have added a print statement after the SECRET_KEY and it prints out (test) as that is what I currently have in the docker-compose.yml file but this should fail to build...

If I hard code the DEBUG I can get it to change but I have completely removed the secret key and the project still starts. Any ideas where Django could be pulling this from or how I am able to trace it back to see?

settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG')
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        container_name: django
        command: gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
        environment:
            - ENVIRONMENT=development
            - SECRET_KEY=(test)
            - DEBUG=0
            - DB_USERNAME=(test)
            - DB_PASSWORD=(test)
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
    celery:
        build: .
        image: celery
        container_name: celery
        command: celery -A config worker -l INFO
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        environment:
            - SECRET_KEY=(test)
            - DEBUG=0
            - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=['127.0.0.1','localhost']
            - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
            - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
        depends_on: 
            - db
            - redis
    celery-beat:
        build: .
        environment: 
            - SECRET_KEY=(test)
            - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
            - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be this way?  DEBUG=True or DEBUG=False

Answer (score 0):

The reason was False/0 from the docker-compose.yml were being formatted to a string and a string is evaluated to True.

To solve this use;

```
DEBUG=eval(os.environ.get('DEBUG', False))
```

or

```
DEBUG=int(os.environ.get('DEBUG', 0))
```

Comment: As side note, It could be better `DEBUG = (os.getenv('DEBUG', False) == 'True')` to compare against the string 'True' and set a boolean to the var (I think it's not an issue in this case, but I try to avoid eval() as much as 777 everywhere I can, plus this way you're  explicitly saying what's expected)